# cublas cublasZgemm() slower than expected

Tags: python, cuda, ctypes, cublas

According to [nvidia](http://developer.nvidia.com/cublas). cublasZgemm is 6x faster than intel MKL.

However, on my PC (i7 2600, Nvidia gtx560, OS:linux 64bit), cublasZgemm is slightly slower than MKL.

I use the numpy.dot() that come with [enthought python distribution](http://enthought.com/products/epd.php) which links numpy against MKL 10.3.

A matrix multiplication function using cublasZgemm is compiled in a shared library and is called using ctypes in a python script.

When multiply two 1024x1024 complex matrices. numpy.dot() took 84ms. The ctypes function call spent 110ms while the cublasZgemm() part took 97ms.

I wonder why cublassZgemm is not as fast as nvidia stated?

Comment: The GPU you have is __much__ slower in double precision performance than the one which NVIDIA used to produce the benchmark numbers.

Comment: To expand on @talonmies' answer, Fermi GPUs that are not used in Tesla cards have been artificially limited to double precision speed one quarter of what the chips are capable. I presume that he did not enter his reply as an answer because you didn't mention which type of numbers you are multiplying.

Comment: @RogerDahl: No, he did - ZGEMM is double precision complex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too bad that they limit the speed of double precision operation.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the info. I'm wondering why you submitted a good answer as a comment then?

Comment: @RogerDahl: Because I don't know for sure what the double precision performance of a consumer compute 2.1 card is.

Comment: Are you sure you were using complex in numpy.dot() ? I am getting 56ms for double precision vs 225ms for double precision complex when using MKL (through matlab). Granted I am using an older cpu (i7 960), but i don't think the 2600 is 3 times faster than the 960.

Comment: @talonmies can you please enter your comment as an answer?  Regardless of the exact double precision performance of specific GeForce cards, the fact is that they are significantly slower than Tesla on fp64 computation.

Comment: @RogerDahl: the GTX 560 GPU does not have "artificially" limited fp64 performance.  The GF114 chip it is based on has a different SM from the GTX 580 (GF110), and as such does not have hardware to optimize fp64 performance.  You may notice that there are no Tesla cards based on GF114 -- GF114 is designed for consumer-class products.

Comment: @Pavan Maybe the 2600 performs better because of the AVX instruction set.

Comment: @lucaspeng I am not sure if it has to do with AVX. Just tested on a sandybridge cpu  (mobile processor i7-2630qm). It takes ~300ms.

Comment: @Pavan That's strange. I'm pretty sure that I am using complex number with numpy.dot(), since the result is complex and is identical with zgemm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder why cublassZgemm is not as fast as nvidia stated?

The short answer is because you used a much slower GPU to perform the benchmarking of zgemm than was used by NVIDIA to generate their performance figures. Your GTX560 is probably about *eight times* slower in double precision performance than the Telsa M2090 that was used by NVIDIA in your link.